# how to add custom image and text to multiple facebook share on a single web page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

I have 8 graphs on my website and I want to share each one of them with a separate image and text. I have found several answers relating to meta tags but that can only be included once.

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Provide 8 individual URLs, that deliver the correct meta data for one image each.

Comment: Thanks,will all the meta tag will be included in the head tag?my code looks something like this....               <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=190344557701042&amp;u=http%3A%2F%2Finfo-design-lab.github.io%2FTN2016%2F%23graph1" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                    Share on facebook
                    </a>